# please need to fix this : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/testttt.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import mysql.connector
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
> ```

this is my code

```
import mysql.connector
```

this the link I used to download the python connector 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

I'am using IDEL

any advise to fix this Error

Note if I call import mysql in my win 10 Comm prompt i don't get any error 
but in IDEL I got this error

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure on all the information, but let me try and help. I would suggest running using pip (the python package manager) to install the MySQL connector. You can run `pip install mysql-connector-python`, as recommended here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I tried this but still the same issue